# How to improve the communication time in restlet based applications?

Tags: performance, swing, restlet, tomcat7

We have a swing UI that is a restlet client. We are accessing the services on the LAN, but the communication is taking a bit long. We are using Tomcat 7.0 and mysql on the server side. 
Is it a known issue with restlet based applications ?
How can we speedup the communication time?

Comment: Which version and client connector of Restlet are you using?

Comment: Hey Jerome, sorry for responding late, we are using Restlet 2.0.9

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.0 the internal HTTP client isn't designed for speed/production purpose, more for developement/convenience purpose. This has been redesigned in version 2.1.

However, in version 2.0, you can drop "org.restlet.ext.net.jar" in your classpath to switch from the internal connector to a faster one based on HTTPUrlConnection.